# REST API filter queries - handling OR operations

Tags: rest, api-design

I am trying to create a nice helper class to parse some query parameters so they can be used to filter an array of data.

I am using the following syntax for my query parameters:

`?filter[name,contains,string]=foo // name field contains the string "foo"`

`?filter[id,gte,number]=123 // item field is greater then or equal to 123`

`?filter[type,eq,string]=foo|bar // type field is equal to "foo" or "bar"`

(you can also use `,` between the values to act as an AND operator, but on a single field, it doesn't have many use cases eg gt 1 AND 2 isn't a great filter)

These query params can be combined, eg

`?filter[name,contains,string]=foo&filter[id,gte,number]=123`

And this will act as an AND condition, meaning data is returned that matches both filters.

Great so far. But I want to implement an OR condition for multiple separate filters.

`?filter[]=...` is used for the actual filter query, so I can't really use that to set the OR condition.

I've tried finding REST API implementations that use somethig similar to this filtering syntax, the closest is Laravel, but the docs don't go into any details about it.

Hoping someone can point me to a good resource about REST API filtering/help me figure out a nice way to implement the OR condition.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think if you want the flexibility you're looking for, it'll probably be best to define a proper grammar and accept a "filter string" that follows that syntax. This would mean you have to define the grammar and behavior of defaults, parse it, and turn it into a query that matches your underlying storage system (e.g., a SQL query or ORM API calls).

For example, this might make your filters look something like:

`?filter=name:("foo" AND id >= 123) OR id <= 567`

And it turns out that there's quite a lot to decide when you start introducing complex filtering operations.

For more reading, Google's API filtering syntax and guidelines are: https://google.aip.dev/160 and the EBNF grammar is https://google.aip.dev/assets/misc/ebnf-filtering.txt